# Python Statsmodels: is there any way to program exogenous variables into the VAR framework the package provides?

Tags: python, statistics, var, statsmodels

Can't post my code as I'm typing on my phone (current employer doesn't allow posting on stackexchange from the computers)
I'm trying to estimate and forecast with a VAR using statsmodels in python, just wondering if there's any way I can introduce exogenous variables into the mix? If not, would anyone be able to provide a framework to do this manually?

Cheers!

Comment: exog option has been added to VAR in statsmodels as part of VECM addition, but it's only available in statsmodels master and not yet in a released version.

Comment: So basically - not yet?

Comment: It's available if you install statsmodels from source.

Comment: Ah I see, I'm not really able to install any packages through my work desktop, could you suggest any workarounds?

Comment: http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/statespace.html#vector-autoregressive-moving-average-with-exogenous-regressors-varmax is already in 0.8, AFAIR, but doesn't have all the post-estimation extras yet

Comment: I think this might be fine, thank you!